# int pointer typecasted with char pointer throw unexpected output?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

Hello int pointer type casted with char pointer throw unexpected output?
below is my code please help me to understand

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
{     
  int arr[3]={2,3,4};
  char*p;
  p=(char*)arr;
  printf("%d\n",*p); // here 2 its good 
  p=p+8;
  printf("%d\n",*p);//here 4 why not 1?
 }
```

Comment: no... without considering the typo, it should be 4.

Comment: is that supposed to be `int arr[3] = {2,3,4};`? There are no `int*` in your example.

Comment: Bits aren't bytes. chars are 1 byte long, not 8 bytes long. arr+8 is outside of the array and so could print anything or crash.

Comment: *p=p+8 is pointing to memory address which hold integer value 3* -- Only if `ints` are 8 bytes long. *i.e 1st bit 1 and 2nd bit 2 so p=p+8 means first bit of memory* -- no, bits don't have individual adddesses, bytes do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code causes undefined behaviour.  First, I'll assume you actually meant:

```
 char arr[3] = {2,3,4};
```

Rather than what you have there.  Then yes, your first print statement is correct and will output 2.  The second one though, anything could happen.  You have an array 3 bytes long and now you're pointing 8 bytes past its starting address.  *Anything* could be there, so your print could show any output at all.

If you had instead:

```
int arr[3] = {2,3,4};
```

Your second output would show either `4` or `0`, depending on whether or not you have a little- or big-endian system, respectively.  Assuming you have a 4-byte `int` type, that is.

Comment: lets take it is little endian then why 4 please explain?

Comment: @carrercarrer *Why not?* (int)2 is 4 bytes long, so adding p+4 points to the 3. (int)3 is 4 bytes long, so p+8 points to the 4. That much is obvious ... what isn't obvious is why you think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant this :

```
char arr[3] = {2,3,4};
```

Now , p is a pointer of type char, when you increment it by 8 it points to some invalid 
memory location that lies outside the char array (since you have allocated space for 3
members inside arr), which may very well contain garbage.
And in that case the output is unpredictable as it may be garbage or you might get a valid
value.